How can I disable the console window's maximize button, resize by drag, and X button in Windows 11?
I want to disable the console window's maximize button, resize by drag, and X button in a C++ program.
But it doesn't work with this code:
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    DeleteMenu(GetSystemMenu(GetConsoleWindow(), FALSE), SC_MAXIMIZE, MF_GRAYED); // maximize button
    EnableMenuItem(GetSystemMenu(GetConsoleWindow(), FALSE), SC_CLOSE, MF_GRAYED); // X button
    DrawMenuBar(GetConsoleWindow());

    return 0;
}

I remember this worked on Windows 10.
Is this a Windows 11 problem, or is there another way to solve it?

You cannot do that. You have decided to write a program that executes in the CONSOLE subsystem. There is no reliable way to query the console host GUI. Indeed, there may not even be a GUI at all. What's the specific problem you are trying to solve here?

Refer to the Blog:Windows Terminal is now the Default in Windows 11
On win10, the default terminal is Windows Console Host. I suggest you could set the default terminal to Windows Console Host in win11.
Settings -> System -> For developers -> Terminal



Don’t use global state to manage a local problem. This proposed answer fails to identify the core issue and suggests a heavy-handed workaround instead. Not useful.

This answer only explains why the code broke, but not how to fix it so it works with the new system

Since consoles can now be tabbed together into a single window, it'd be rude to disable the caption buttons on your window, because that would prevent the user from using those buttons with the other consoles in your window.
